# How to prove $a^ma^n = a^{m+n}$ using field axioms?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I came across this while doing questions on field axioms. I need this proved for where $m,n \in \mathbb Z$ and $a \neq 0$. Please do it in complete steps. I looked this up on the site but I couldn't understand what's been done.

Comment: Is this about elementary exponents ?

Comment: $(a\times a\times....)\times(a\times a\times....)=a\times a\times....a\times a\times....$ by the associative property of the real numbers

Comment: For positive integers $m,n$ this can be shown by (as @tired comments) induction using the associated property.  For non-positive integers the field axioms come into additional force in providing that $a\neq 0$ has an inverse, and thus one builds on the positive integer case by observing that $a^{-m}$ is the inverse of $a^m$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of a real number `a` and integers `m` and `n` it could be easily proven by definition.

So what is `a^m`: `a * a * ... * a` m times. (1)

So what is `a^n`: `a * a * ... * a` n times. (2)

The same is with `a^(m + n)`: `a * a * ... * a` m + n times. (3)

When we multiply (1) and (2) we got `a * a * ... * a` m + n times which is equal to (3).

It means that we proved the identity.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of $a^m$ is by induction on $m$. So the best way to prove what you want to prove is by induction. As $a^0= 1$by definition, what you want to prove is immediate for $n=0$. The step $n=1$ is interesting for the step $n\to n+1$. $a^{m+1} = a^m a$ by definition and so $a^{m+1} = a^m a^1$. Now the step $n\to n+1$ follows easily from the definitions

Comment: Can you elaborate more. I'm having trouble understanding. Thank you.

Comment: What part are you having trouble understanding ? (So I know what to elaborate)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the answer. You have to consider all the values for m and n such that $m,n\in\mathbb Z^+$, $m,n\in\mathbb Z^-$,  $m,n = 0$ and $m\in\mathbb Z^+ and, n\in\mathbb Z^- s.t. m>n$.
[image: This shows step by step proof.]